# "Мне забывать не положено" - тип сказуемого

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, тип-сказуемого

Вынуждена, признавая свою некомпетентность, обратиться за помощью. Если сказуемое "забывать не положено", то какого оно типа? По моим рассуждениям, это не СГС, поскольку тут не модальная связка + инфинитив, а именная часть и зависимый инфинитив, и по этой же причине это не СИС (нет связки). Что в моих мыслях пошло не так?

Answer (score 2):

***МнЕ забывать // не положено.***

1) Это  **односоставное** безличное предложение, ИНВЕРСИЯ инфинитива и связки **связана с его актуальным членением.** 
При обычном порядке слов предложение выглядит так: ***Мне не положено забывать.***  (Инверсия позволяет выделить логическим ударением нужные слова).

2) ***Не положено (нельзя) забывать***   — составное глагольное сказуемое.

Связкой является не модальный глагол, а **краткая форма причастия с модальным значением.**

3) **Примечания:**

1) Вид сказуемого определяется по его структуре, в данном случае это  **модальная связка и основная часть в форме инфинитива.**

2) **В роли модальной связки**  также могут выступать краткие модальные прилагательные: должен, обязан, готов, рад и др.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (о двусоставном предложении)**

Предложенный вариант разбора предложения как двусоставного мне **представляется некорректным.**

Вот пример двусоставного предложения: ***Бегать по утрам полезно (полезная привычка).*** Бегать — подлежащее, полезно — именная часть сказуемого.

Принципиальная разница вариантов в том, что **краткое прилагательное в этом примере не имеет модального значения.**

Answer (score 1):

Второй ответ я исправляю.

У Кустовой в "Синтаксисе современного русского языка" такие предложения считаются **односоставными безличными,** а причастия  названы **причастными предикативами с модальным значением.** Приведены такие примеры: *Запрещено открыать люк. Не положено разговаривать.*

**Никакого намека на двусоставное предложение.**

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, есть разные мнения по этому поводу. Например, можете посмотреть статью https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/o-sintaksicheskoy-funktsii-infinitiva-v-sochetanii-so-slovami-na-o
У меня есть шпаргалка для таких случаев, подходящая для школьников. Не помню, откуда брала информацию, к сожалению. Но все же поделюсь, вдруг автору пригодится.

*Иногда при определении главных членов решающим является порядок слов:
Стать моряком – его мечта. Его мечта – стать моряком.
!!! Трудность : когда инфинитив сочетается со словами на –О.

**1. Инфинитив  +  слово на –О**   -  двусоставное предложение с подлеж. - инфинитивом:
Спорить с ним бесполезно. Шутить с либерализмом опасно.

Перестановка инфинитива на второе место превращает предложение в безличное с СГС:

**2. Слово на –о  +  инфинитив**
Бесполезно спорить с ним. Непросто было добраться до работы в этот день из-за метели. Опасно шутить с либерализмом.

**Наличие при инфинитиве слов с ярким модальным значением
надо, нужно, необходимо, нельзя, можно и др.
говорит о том, что это сказуемое безличных предложений, независимо от порядка слов:** У вас тут можно заблудиться. Спрашивать об этом было нельзя. Надо найти другое решение.*
Слово (которое в школе относят к категории состояния)"не положено" имеет яркое модальное значение, соответственно, мы имеем дело с односоставным безличным предложением, СГС.

Answer (score 0):

Два одинаковых предложения совеременный синтаксис трактует по-разному (!??)

```
1. Мне забывать не положено
2. Мне забывать не позволено
```

В (2): СИС (не позволено) + дополнение (забывать). Поскольку выполняется принцип разносубъектности действий: `Мне забывать Васей не позволено`.

[О СИНТАКСИЧЕСКИХ ФУНКЦИЯХ ИНФИНИТИВА В ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯХ ТИПА РЕШЕНО ЕХАТЬ/ВЕЛЕНО ЕХАТЬ](http://naukarus.com/o-sintaksicheskih-funktsiyah-infinitiva-v-predlozheniyah-tipa-resheno-ehat-veleno-ehat)

https://cyberpedia.su/17x6049.html

В (1) : СИС (не положено) + СГС (не положено + забывать). Поскольку хотя и выполняется принцип разносубъектности действий, но, во-первых, нельзя подставить субъект в творительном падеже (Мне забывать Васей(???) не положено), а во-вторых, *положено* в отличии от *позволено*, видите ли, является модальным словом (так как не имеет парного глагола: позволено-позволять, но положено-полагать(???)).

Comment: Именно! Зависит от точки зрения, есть разные мнения у разных исследователей.  Посмотрите статью, которую я прикрепила, там об этом написано. У Бабайцевой и Лекант одно мнение, у Шахматова другое.