# Как определить вид сказуемого в заданном предложении

Tags: тип-сказуемого

Это всем известные строки из "Горя от ума":

***— Служить бы рад, прислуживаться тошно.***

Два простых предложения в составе БСП.

**Вопросы:**

Как определяется **вид предложений и вид сказуемого** в каждом из них?

Это **односоставные или двусоставные предложения**? Есть ли в них **инверсия** и с чем она связана?

Спасибо.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Уважаемые участники форума, я надеюсь, что вы выскажете свое мнение. В Сети приводятся разнообразные и весьма странные разборы этого предложения. Давайте вместе составим правильное решение.

Answer (score 1):

Я очень надеялась, что вопрос заинтересует наших педагогов: ведь это обычный школьный разбор, и наверняка он встречался  в их практике. Еще раз повторяю, что видела ответы в Сети, и они были разнообразными и  весьма оригинальными.

Разбираю по Кустовой:

***Служить бы рад, прислуживаться тошно.***

В обоих предложениях использована инверсия, то есть перестановка инфинитива с целью выделения его логическим ударением.

При прямом порядке слов: *Рад бы служить, тошно прислуживаться.*

Возможна постановка **тире, а не запятой**   для обозначения противопоставления в БСП.

1) ***Служить бы рад.***

**Двусоставное неполное предложение** (Римма подсказала, спасибо ей).

**Сказуемое:** рад бы служить (был бы рад служить), составное глагольное.

Вспомогательная часть выражена кратким прилагательным ***рад*** со связкой ***был бы*** (*был* – пропущено) в форме сослагательного наклонения.

Это обычная практика **для модельных слов** (существительных, кратких прилагательных), которые не могут выразить время и наклонение, в отличие от вспомогательных глаголов: *я рад служить, я был рад служить, я был бы рад служить.* **Сравнить**: *я хочу служить, я хотел служить, я хотел бы служить.*

2) ***Прислуживаться тошно.***

**Цитирую:**

Предикативы могут употребляться с примыкающим инфинитивом: *интересно узнать, страшно вспомнить, пора ехать, грех жаловаться.*

(Предикативами называют слова категории состояния, материал рассматривается в теме "безличные предложения").

Итак, ***тошно прислуживаться***.

Это односоставное безличное предложение.

**Сказуемое:**  составное глагольное,  вспомогательная часть выражена модальным предикативом ***тошно*** со значением состояния человека.

Answer (score 0):

Инфинитивные. Рад бы;   тошно.

Двусоставные, двусоставные. И инверсии нет.

Answer (score 0):

```
         Фамусов
 Сказал бы я, во-первых: не блажи,  
 Именьем, брат, не упрекай оплошно,
 А, главное, поди-тка послужи.  

         Чацкий
 Служить бы рад, прислуживаться тошно.
```

(Рассуждения мои — школьного уровня.)

1. Это предложение часто фигурирует в правилах — как пример БСП с тире.
   Объяснение, приблизительно, такое: во втором предложении имеется противопоставление; между предложениями можно вставить союзы **а, но.**
   *Служить бы рад — прислуживаться тошно.* — *Служить бы рад, **а** прислуживаться тошно.*
2. [Я] **Служить бы рад.**
   Неполное двусоставное предложение: *я* — подлежащее пропущено (оно восстанавливается из контекста); *служить бы рад* — составное именное сказуемое.
   Думаю, что инверсия присутствует.
   Обычный порядок слов, возможно, должен быть таким: *Я был бы рад (по)служить.*
3. **Прислуживаться тошно.**
   Двусоставное: *прислуживаться* — подлежащее (инфинитив); *тошно* — составное именное сказуемое (краткое прилагательное от *тошный*, глагол-связка пропущен).
   Прислуживаться (каково?) тошно. [*Труд упорный ему (Онегину) был тошен.*]

Comment: 1) Ну что тут сказать. 1) Могу гарантировать, что первое решение НЕВЕРНОЕ.  Это односоставное определенно-личное предложение. Сказуемое составное глагольное, рад бы - модальная связка, выраженная кратким прилагательным. Этот вариант разбирается в учебниках, поэтому я уверена в нем.

Comment: 2) Здесь решение не такое очевидное, многое зависит от того, как определить связку. Если рассматривать ее как модальную, то это тоже составное глагольное сказуемое: (мне) тошно (не хочется) прислуживаться. Кроме того, СУБЪЕКТ действия относится к  пропущенному местоимению "мне", поэтому предложение односоставное безличное, это тот же субъект, который в первом предложении присутствует как  пропущенное "я" в определенно-личном предложении.

Comment: Сказуемое в определенно-личных предложениях выражается формой 1 или 2 лица глаголов единственного или множественного числа. А у нас (без контекста) может быть и 3 лицо. Он служить бы рад.

Comment: Ну хорошо, пусть будет неполное двусоставное. А всё остальное? Частица БЫ к чему относится? Я был бы рад служить.

Comment: Ну совсем меня "запинали"!.. Ваш вопрос, бесспорно, интересен. Я на него ответила, опираясь на те знания, которые у меня есть; я его заценила. КАК это предложение разбирается в учебниках — не в курсе. Думаю, однозначного ответа мы не найдём.

Comment: Извините, Римма, меня тут с утра тоже "запинали" по этой же теме,. Никто ответить не хочет или не может, я не знаю,  вот на этот вопрос. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452358/Мне-забывать-не-положено-тип-сказуемого  И наследующий (вот этот)  никто не отвечает, только вот Вы. А ответить НУЖНО, причем именно ОДНОЗНАЧНО. Если есть варианты, надо обосновать каждый, определить, при каких условиях  они верны. Иначе мне просто неловко за форум "Русский язык". А еще боремся за разные там звания.

Comment: $Sharon Мы и за звания боремся?! Ну спасибо, повеселили. Тогда надо нанимать профессионалов. Дорого? - тогда надо отказаться от "честолюбивых" планов. Кстати, а зачем нам звания? Вот лично вам зачем? ))

Comment: @Sharon, не могу согласиться с Риммой Михайловной в том, что первое часть "Служить бы рад"  даусаставное неполное. Да, можно вставить местоимение он, но тогда первая часть не будет соотноситься со второй.

Comment: Я только не понял, как разбирает Кустова.

Comment: Эх-эх, Серж! «Простите, ваше имя-отчество не Юлия Владимировна?» — «Марфа Васильевна я...»

Comment: @Римма Михайлова, вы о чем это?

Comment: О том, что неправильно написал ваше отчество?

Comment: Извините, я просто пыталась пошутить и просто обратить Ваше внимание (безобидно, с помощью цитаты Булгакова) на то, что Римма Михайлова я... Не получилось — извините ещё раз.

Comment: Все нормально... )

Comment: Я не специально. По невнимательности.