# Деепричастный оборот при опущенном глаголе

Tags: деепричастный-оборот, инфинитив

*Желательно именно в таком порядке, подчеркивая интересующую вас неоднородность.*

Вот написал такую сентенцию - и поймал себя на том, что править не хочется, а уверенности нет.

*Для понимания. Речь шла вот о чем. Есть фраза, в которой присутствуют два члена предложения, в отношении которых нет уверенности, однородны они или нет. Так вот эти два члена предложения рекомендуется поменять местами, после чего (по моему предположению) неоднородность будет более очевидна.*

Известно, что фразы типа "*Желательно **писать** именно в таком порядке, подчеркивая интересующую вас неоднородность*" Розенталь и современные грамматики вообще допускают без лишних оговорок. Но у меня инфинитив опущен...

Answer (score 2):

***Желательно (писать) именно в таком порядке, подчеркивая интересующую вас неоднородность.***

1) **Ответ на вопрос**

Мне такой вариант кажется **вполне приемлемым.** По тексту ясно, что в безличном предложении пропущен инфинитив, к которому относятся два однородных обстоятельства, одно из которых выражено деепричастным оборотом.

Позиция деепричастного оборота, **расположенного на расстоянии от безличного сказуемого,** практически  не сказывается на стилистике предложения.

Пропуск инфинитива был бы некорректен в таком варианте: *Желательно (писать), подчеркивая интересующую вас неоднородность.*

2) **О спорной грамматике при обсуждении**

Надо признаться, что меня заинтересовала именно эта часть вопроса, так как  эта тема  была для меня (где-то месяц назад) очень актуальной. **Это различение двусоставных и безличных односоставных предложений при наличии инфинитива.**

Тогда форум дружно проигнорировал эту тему, так что я могу озвучить только **два мнения**, которые я считаю неверными.

***Прислуживаться тошно***

[Как определить вид сказуемого в заданном предложении](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452363/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)

(1) Двусоставное: ***прислуживаться*** — **подлежащее** (инфинитив); тошно — составное именное сказуемое (краткое прилагательное от тошный, глагол-связка пропущен).

(2) Инфинитивные. Рад бы; тошно.  **Двусоставные, двусоставные.** И инверсии нет.

***Мне забывать не положено.*** 
["Мне забывать не положено" - тип сказуемого](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452358/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)

***Забывать*** – **подлежащее**, не положено – сказуемое.
Как в школьном примере: Читать – полезно.

**"А еще кто-нибудь из грамматистов допускает подобное "подлежащее" в безличных предложениях?!"** Как видите, наши участники допускают такое подлежащее.

А это мой призыв о помощи:

***Уважаемые участники форума, я надеюсь, что вы выскажете свое мнение. В Сети приводятся разнообразные и весьма странные разборы этого предложения. Давайте вместе составим правильное решение.***

Да вот только практически никто не откликнулся на него (кроме одного участника, **которому я очень благодарна**). А второй участник, мой вечный оппонент, поставил мне минус за инакомыслие. (Речевые оценки впоследствии убрали).

Comment: Что касается спорности грамматики, то она тоже весьма условна. Реальная "спорность" возникает тогда, когда в рамках одной модели возникпет возможность для разного прочтения синтаксиса. А у нас если и спор просто терминологический. Школьные подходы относят инфинитивные предложения к безличным, академики в большинстве своем склонны считать самостоятельным типом. Аналогично с категорией состояния. У них просто модели разные, то есть "спор" чисто терминологический. Из серии "стакан наполовину пуст или наполовину полон?".

Comment: *Как видите, наши участники допускают такое подлежащее.* - я не про участников. Участники много чего допускают. Но вы подменяете вопрос. Инфинитив в роли "подлежащего" - это не новость, но тут просто терминологическая заморочка. Такие предложения лучше считать отдельным типом предложений. Но этом они всегда ***односоставные***, следовательно "подлежащее" - весьма условное название для единственного главного члена...

Comment: Я сообразил, что вы говорите о своем вопросе по ссылке... Ну это не совсем по теме получается. Там модальное значение размыто. Если мне память не изменяет, квалификацию предложений подобного типа осложняет именно возможная инверсия. Если модальное слово оказывается в конце предложения, то его модальность становится сомнительной. Если не ошибаюсь, об этом есть у Валгиной. Но не буду здесь злостно оффтопить.

Comment: Я так не считаю.  В вузовской грамматике речь идет о безличных односоставных предложения, там в состав именного сказуемого входит предикативное наречие и инфинитив. Они отличаются от двусоставных предложений, в которых инфинитив является подлежащим. Но эти предложения не называются инфинитивными. Инфинитивные предложения - это независимый инфинитив (ка пройти в библиотеку),  есть безлично-инфинитивные предложения (нечего читать). В современном синтаксисе стараются четко всё это классифицировать. А если считать, что всё размыто,  то зачем вообще заниматься анализом и разборами.

Comment: *Я так не считаю* - что именно?! Я вас не понял совершенно.

Comment: *В современном синтаксисе стараются четко всё это классифицировать. А если считать, что всё размыто, то зачем вообще заниматься анализом и разборами* - стараются. И не только в современном. Но каждый это делает по-своему. Вы с какими-то химерами воюете. Я не сказал что "все размыто". Просто у каждой будем называть "школы" - своя систематика. Внутри неё все четко. А проблема выбора остается. Классический пример такого двуединого подхода - синхронизм и диахронизм.

Comment: Или скажем, Петроградская и Московская фонетическая школа.У них разная систематика, спорить "как правильно" бессмысленно, все зависит от того, какую систематику мы примем за базовую. .

Comment: Я не считаю, что все дело в терминологической заморочке, я думаю, что грамматика должна быть ближе к точным наукам,  а сейчас там допускается слишком много вольностей и свободных толкований. Мне показалось, что Вас огорчила позиция Б.Б., который посчитал "писать" подлежащим. А фонетические школы я вообще всерьез не воспринимаю, это школы ради школ, практической пользы от них мало.  Но, кажется, система ругается, спасибо Вам за беседу.

Comment: *я думаю, что грамматика должна быть ближе к точным наукам* - вы, во-первых, путаете грамматику и её ***описания*** или модели. Грамматика - она как бы сама по себе, одна единственная, объективно существующая. а то, что мы называем грамматикой - модели, которые до известной степени отражают наши походы. Это заодно и к вопросу о точных науках. Физики-теоретики прекрасно понимают, что работают с моделями , ибо  с самим объектом им, теоретикам, работать напрямую невозможно.

Comment: *Мне показалось, что Вас огорчила позиция Б.Б., который посчитал "писать" подлежащим* - не просто подлежащим, а подлежащим в безличном предложении. Без этого "маленького" нюанса и смысла обсуждать речения ББ нету.

Comment: Кстати, я давно заметил, что филологи очень не любят упоминания о существовании разных школ. Даже упоминание того простого факта, что школьное "первое спряжение" в АГ традиционно называется "вторым" - и наоборот, вызывает у них некое подобие ступора. Вот споры о том,  какой из этих подходов правильнее, я и называю терминологическими.

Comment: Я полагаю, что вы с Б.Б. друг друга не поняли, у него писать - подлежащее, желательно - сказуемое. Это верно? Вы это допускаете? А вся современная фонология - это софистика (искусное словоплетение)  и  кормушка для псевдонауки. Но это уже мое личное мнение.

Comment: Кстати говоря, мне тоже сначала пришла в голову идея об обособленном обстоятельстве, однако я её сразу же отмёл из-за того, что, *как мне показалось*, ДО должен быть обязательно связан с глаголом. Неужели отсутствие данной связи возможно?

Comment: *что вы с Б.Б. друг друга не поняли* - Не подсказывайте. пусть сам и напишет, что у него что. А то опять свалит на мою невнимательность. Но вообще-то грамматический разбор начинают с определения типа предложения. Без этого разговоры о подлежащем и сказуемом бессмысленны. Насчеи фонологии - даже и не мечтайте, что я с вами соглашусь. Но здесь это оффтоп, я привел вам как пример возможности разных подходов. Один многих возможных, не более того. Но если вы намерены писать прожекты о введении единомыслия в России, то это не со мной и не здесь.

Comment: @behemothus Вам кто-либо говорил, что я намеренно делал грамматический разбор? В своих ответах я использую исключительно необходимое „оборудование” и описываю его использование.

Comment: @Aer ***Вам*** я все сказал. Вы можете наконец сказать, какого типа рассматриваемые предложения? Больше повторять вопрос не буду.

Answer (score -1):

Данное написание неуместно, как я думаю. В этом случае предложение из безличного превращается в двусоставное („желательное” — субстантивированное прилагательное в роли подлежащего, а „именно в таком порядке” — составное именное сказуемое, выраженное существительным в косвенном падеже с предлогом и зависимым словом „такой”. „Именно” — выделительно-ограничительная частица и также входит в состав оборота). В действительности получился следующий переход:

«**Писать**, подчёркивая интересующую вас неоднородность».

«Желательное (**есть**) именно в таком порядке, подчеркивая интересующую вас неоднородность».

То есть полноценный глагол с полным значением был заменён на глагол-связку „есть”, обозначающий состояние и, *как я понимаю*, не имеющий возможности иметь при себе какое-либо деепричастие.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95342/discussion-on-answer-by-------).